# label that shows Coordinates of mouse

Tags: java, swing, label, coordinates, mouse

At university we started Java programming and got the task to write a program that draws a vertical and a horizontal line at the location where the mouse currently is. Also we should add a Label that shows the coordinates of the mouse. I got the drawing thing working but when I try to add a label, it won't show up? I started with a test-label, but even that isn't shown inside the frame. Can someone help me?

```
public class Coordinates extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

private Point currentPoint = new Point(-50, -50);


public Coordinates(){
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);


}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.drawLine(currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y+1000, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y-1000);
    g.drawLine(currentPoint.x+1000, currentPoint.y, currentPoint.x-1000, currentPoint.y);

}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){

    currentPoint = e.getPoint();
    repaint();
};

static JLabel label = new JLabel();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Koordinaten");
    frame.setSize(600, 400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(label);

    JComponent newContentPane = new Coordinaten();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true);

    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

}


public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}





public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    label.setText(currentPoint.toString());

    currentPoint = e.getPoint();
    repaint();
}
```

}

Comment: Sorry, but I see no JLabel anywhere in the code that you've posted. Where is it?

Comment: As a side recommendation, do all drawing within the JPanel's paintComponent method and be sure to call the super's method within your override, usually at the start of the override method.

Comment: yes sorry I didn't put the label in the code, I thought one of you can show me how to put it inside?

Comment: If you don't show us how you're trying to do it, how can we tell what you're doing wrong?

Comment: [How to create a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) should show you how to create and add a label

Comment: OK, you're covering over your JLabel with the added contentPane. Add your JLabel to the **JPanel** that you draw on (see my code for example).

Comment: in my case, the panel is Coordinates right? I mean where I also have addMouseListener(this); ,....

Comment: @beginner_T: try it and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do all your painting within the JPanel's `paintComponent` method not the paint method, and be sure to call the super's `paintComponent` method within your override, usually at the start of the override method.
2. You need to add a JLabel to your JPanel to have it display anything. Your code does not do this. And then in the MouseMotionListener, set the JLabel's text with the mouse coordinates.

For example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 600;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
    private JLabel locationLabel = new JLabel();

    public DrawPanel() {
        add(locationLabel);
        addMouseMotionListener(new MyMouseAdapter());
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);  // this allows JPanel to do housekeeping painting first

        // do drawing here!

    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            // get Point location and turn into a String
            String location = String.format("[%d, %d]", e.getX(), e.getY());

            // set the label's text with this String
            locationLabel.setText(location);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("DrawPanel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new DrawPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

With the cross-hairs:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 600;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
    private JLabel locationLabel = new JLabel();
    private int mouseX = 0;
    private int mouseY = 0;

    public DrawPanel() {
        add(locationLabel);
        addMouseMotionListener(new MyMouseAdapter());
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); // this allows JPanel to do housekeeping
                                 // painting first

            // do drawing here!
            g.drawLine(0, mouseY, getWidth(), mouseY);
            g.drawLine(mouseX, 0, mouseX, getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            mouseX = e.getX();
            mouseY = e.getY();

            // get Point location and turn into a String
            String location = String.format("[%d, %d]", mouseX, mouseY);

            // set the label's text with this String
            locationLabel.setText(location);

            repaint();
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("DrawPanel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new DrawPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, would be great if you could show me a sample code, I am really new to programming

Comment: @beginner_T: example code posted, but in the future, please don't ask for code as you should always show your attempt to solve it first -- including your adding the JLabel to the JPanel and your attempt to set its text. Better for us to work with your code, not mine.

Comment: I edited my code and how I tried it, but it's still not working.. I know that it is better to use paintComponent, but we learned it like this (idk why), and I guess in the test we should do it as we learned it, even if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @beginner_T: you don't want to add all that junk to the JFrame as you're covering over previously added content with the newest content since JFrame uses a BorderLayout. Add the JLabel to the drawing JPanel as I do above. The JPanel uses FlowLayout and so the label will be added to the top in the middle. Run my code to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, a JLabel is made like this, defined outside of the main method:

```
static JLabel label = new JLabel();
```

In your main method

```
frame.add(label);
```

And in your mouseMoved method you would put this:

```
label.setText(currentPoint.toString());
```

Comment: I tried that, but it shows me an error at frame.add(label); it says : Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field label

Comment: @beginner_T here's your next programming challenge, do a quick search of SO, that is a common beginner mistake and gets asked a lot. So, when faced with a problem, try seeing if some one else has also suffered from it first ;)

Comment: I've updated my response. Also, you should call super.paint(g) at the begining of your paint method. What would happen now is that the Panel would not be cleared before it was drawn on, and you get a series of lines.

Comment: I really appreciate your help and now the error is gone... but still the label is not showing?! :(

Comment: You want to add the label after you cal lframe.setContentPane. Right now the JPanel is covering the label.